# Deblurred images in Matlab by division process

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to deblur the images by dividing the blurred image in the frequency domain by specific filter also in the frequency domain ... the problem is the result of division is `NaN`! The image is also completely black.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  My code is below:

```
G1 =  imread('B1.jpg');
figure, imshow (G1); 
% FFT for B1
G_1 = fftshift(G1); 
G_1 = fft2(G_1); 
G_1 = ifftshift(G_1);
figure, imshow( G_1); 

h_1 = fspecial( 'gaussian', [512 512] , 1.0 );
% Fourier Transform of 2D Gaussian 
H_1 = fftshift(h_1);
H_1 = fft2(H_1); 
H_1 = ifftshift(H_1); 
figure, imshow (abs (H_1) ,[ ]);

% Apply the filter for Image G_1 
 F_1a = G_1 ./ H_1; 
F_1a = ifftshift (F_1a); 
F_1a = ifft2 (F_1a); 
F_1a = fftshift (F_1a); 
figure, imshow (F_1a);
```

You can find the `B1` image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can get a NaN anytime both your numerator and denominator are both zero.  Furthermore, anytime your denominator is zero, you'll get an Inf.  Either is bad.  So, after your `G_1./H_1` operation, I'd check for NaN and Inf and replace by zero.

Comment: Totally agree with the NaN divisions here. Also, what the OP is doing is deconvolution, but that is unstable once any slight amount of noise is introduced.  I'm not sure about setting the spectrum to zero when there is `NaN` or `Inf` though... but something to try!

Comment: Instead of dividing by 'H_1' I would have a look at Weiner deconvolution. It will give a more stable result and take into account image noise.  Simply dividing by 'H_1' will boost the noise in your output image considerably

Comment: @docPhil - 100% agree.

Comment: @rayryeng  this is assignment try to compare between wiener2 function and the division process !the division does not work I think for coding mistakes in my code !  and I do not know where is the problem ! I think after the division process I should get unblurred image. but I am not! any idea how to fix this code ?

Comment: If you're supposed to compare them, then perhaps doing this is on purpose. The answer to this question is probably that straight deconvolution is bad and using weiner filtering is preferred!